# Background change not working in javascript. whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-slider

I am using jquery slider, i have a single layout and a center div for content..i need to change the color of the layout while i slide on a different page. This is What i am doing using asp.net mvc3.

HTML:

```
    <div id="iPhone_Product">
            <div class="slides_containeriphone" >
                @if (Model == null)
                {
                    <div class="animateriphone" id="1" title="iphone">

                        @Html.Partial("`enter code here`_iPhone_Main")

                    </div>
                        <div class="animateriphone" id="2" title="salah">
                        @Html.Partial("Salah")
                    </div>
                        <div class="animateriphone" id="3" title="tasbeeh">
                        @Html.Partial("_Tasbeeh")
                    </div>
                }
                else
                { 
                    foreach (string s in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="animateriphone">
                            @Html.Partial(s);
                        </div>
                    }
                }

            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:
    function color_change() {
                var ids = new Array();
                ids[0] = '1';
                ids[1] = '2';
                ids[2] = '3';

```
            for (var item = 0; item < ids.length; item++) {
                var x = document.getElementById(ids[item]);
            }

        if (x.id == '1' && x.title=='iphone') {
            $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "#c8c7c7" });

            }
            else
                if (x.id == '2' && x.title == 'salah') {
                    $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "yellow" });
                }
                else
                    if (x.id == '3' && x.title == 'tasbeeh') {
                        $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "#c8c7c7" });
                    }
                }
      $(document).ready(function () {
    color_change();
    });
```

i have used this javascript to change the background but its not working, any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're not calling the ids right, try this:

```
<div class="animateriphone" id="id2" title="salah">  

var x = document.getElementById('id'+ ids[item]);
```

Comment: the ids in the HTML are simply numeric.  no prefixes to them, however, I think that is the problem.

Comment: fixed again, I'm going to stop coming to SO early in the morning lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using numbers for ids.  Try starting your id values with letters.  I think you should consider prefixing your ids, i.e. id1, id2, or something like that.

And you are closing the for loop too early,  Nest all your if/else logic inside it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't x always going to be 3 since you are reseting x inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over all your elements without doing anything to them, so depending on what you are trying to do, you might need to move the if-statements into the for-loop as well, or make use of the `x` in a proper way from within the for-loop.

Not entirely sure what you want to accomplish, but I've put together what I believe you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuzTU/1/

```
function color_change() { 
    var ids = new Array(); ids[0] = '1'; ids[1] = '2'; ids[2] = '3';
    for (var item = 0; item < ids.length; item++) {
        var x = document.getElementById(ids[item]);

        if (x.id == '1' && x.title=='iphone') {
            $("#" + x.id).css({ "background-color": "#c8c7c7" });

        }
        else if (x.id == '2' && x.title == 'salah') {
            $("#" + x.id).css({ "background-color": "yellow" });
        }
        else if (x.id == '3' && x.title == 'tasbeeh') {
            $("#" + x.id).css({ "background-color": "#c8c7c7" });
        }
    }
}        
$(document).ready(function () {
    color_change();
});​
```

Comment: i have edited my question. if you understand it then please help me.
What you have just done is not enough. i have done this but this is just a partial view inside the body. i have to change the whole body color. thanks.

Comment: @user1774034 I'm still not following you then. You need to clarify how things should work. When shall the background-color change, the background-color of what element and so forth. Try to describe it more thoroughly.

Comment: <div class="animateriphone" id="1" title="iphone">
this div is just a container to place some content. i want to change the background color when i slide to a different view i.e html.partial("salah"). its just a view in a div but i want to change the body background color not the div background color and here(".st_tabs_container") represents the body layout.

Comment: i hope i make sense this time.

Comment: @user1774034 How do you do this "slide", is there some kind of event you can listen for? If I were you, I would try to update the entire question with some additional context. Perhaps you can add some image to show what you are trying to accomplish, and some more code. At the moment, I'm not sure what you are trying to do.